# How can I convert pandas dataframe to tensor and reshape it?

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, keras, pytorch

I'd like to change some dataframe to tensor to make it work on rnn model.
The original shape of data is like this.

```
input : X_train.shape
output : (2101, 32)
```

and the expected shape is

```
output : (2101, 4, 8)
```

I've tried

```
X_train.to_numpy.reshape(-1, 4, 8)
```

but it did not work.

plz help

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the `numpy` method:

```py
X_train.reshape(-1, 4, 8).numpy()
```